# Inserting vue component into Html or even .blade (Laravel) files

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, datepicker, laravel-blade

I'm a backend developer who knows a little bit of jQuery, and I'm struggling to insert a VUE 3 datepicker into an HTML page.
I understand that I would need to study frontend development more deeply, but at the moment, I can't afford to start from scratch to understand how this implementation works.

I would like to use this component: vue3datepicker.com within an HTML file.

I have read the component's documentation, asked in the GPT chat, in some forums I participate in, and searched relentlessly on Google and DuckDuckGo for how to implement third-party components in "static" HTML, but so far, none of the answers have helped me understand how to implement it.

In the section https://vue3datepicker.com/installation/, they mention some installation examples, but I'm more lost than a blind person in a shooting.

If I add the CDN, do I necessarily need to use the import for something else? (i still don't understand well npm and build steps)

I will leave an example of the code I tried to do here, but it is giving me an error:

Vue warn: Failed to resolve component: vuedatepicker
If this is a native custom element, make sure to exclude it from component resolution via compilerOptions.isCustomElement.
at <App>

Vue warn: Property "date" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance.
at <App>

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Title</title>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS v5.2.1 -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-iYQeCzEYFbKjA/T2uDLTpkwGzCiq6soy8tYaI1GyVh/UjpbCx/TYkiZhlZB6+fzT" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@latest"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@vuepic/vue-datepicker@latest"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@vuepic/vue-datepicker@latest/dist/main.css">

</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <!-- place navbar here -->
  </header>
  <main>

    <div id="app">
        <template>
            <VueDatePicker v-model="date"></VueDatePicker>
          </template>
    </div>
      
  </main>
  <footer>
    <!-- place footer here -->
  </footer>


</body>

<script>
    const app = Vue.createApp({
        components: { Datepicker: VueDatePicker },
    }).mount("#app");
</script>

</html>
```

Here some examples working in oficial doc  https://vue3datepicker.com/props/modes-configuration/

Answer (score 1):

In the above code snippet you don't need the template tag and you have to call Datepicker instead of VueDatePicker. Code after correction:

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
        components: { Datepicker: VueDatePicker },
        data() {
        return {
         date: ''
        }
       }
    }).mount("#app");
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Title</title>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS v5.2.1 -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-iYQeCzEYFbKjA/T2uDLTpkwGzCiq6soy8tYaI1GyVh/UjpbCx/TYkiZhlZB6+fzT" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@latest"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@vuepic/vue-datepicker@latest"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@vuepic/vue-datepicker@latest/dist/main.css">

</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <!-- place navbar here -->
  </header>
  <main>

    <div id="app">
        <Datepicker v-model="date"></Datepicker>
    </div>

  </main>
  <footer>
    <!-- place footer here -->
  </footer>
</body>
  </html>
```